Do we want a community blog?
It's possible for a Stack Exchange site to get it's own blog provided we follow some steps to prove a couple things:

We want it
We can make it happen

So you know, the community will take part in posting and vetting the articles, and we'll try and nail down the following before we actually get it:

The Scope
Who will contribute (tentative, we're not locked in to only certain people contributing)
The schedule

As a starting point I really like the Question of the Week (QotW) concept on Security. I think it'd be a great starting point, taking the hottest question of the week and digging into the issue a bit deeper all in one post for easy consumption.
Remember the Blog can be more than a "greatest hits" of our questions/answers. We can also use it to share interesting findings or any form of information sharing that doesn't fit well in the Q&A format.
Is this something we want? The next step would be to define what we want the blog to be about, first I want to know if the support is there. Please vote to indicate your approval and if you have any good suggestions, make them in an answer for when we start the next steps. We'll also need to know who's willing to write and what we want to write about.

I stole this from my own meta.UX question. I probably won't be able to hold the reigns as much as I have with UX, but I thought I'd get the ball rolling.

I would enjoy writing some neuroscience themed articles, and perhaps this would be another chance to connect with the neuroinformatics folks.

Keeping a community blog on a scientific topic stocked with quality content and posts is very hard. cstheory has a much bigger community, with many participants already familiar with blogs (and many having their own), the blog is also picked up by the main TCS aggregator, and still the posts for the blog are generated at a trickle... if we are having issues even asking several questions a  day, where do we expect to get the patience, and passion to run a whole blog?

tl;dr we should think about this after we get a bigger userbase and more questions per day.

I agree with @ArtemKaznatcheev. We don't have enough participation to support a blog activity. i do want one, but am afraid we'll end up with a blog that gets posts only once in  a blue moon.  The Question of the  week idea has the same problem. AFAIK, we don't have enough activity to justify that sustainably either.
